# Can anyone explain this Ruby method to me?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain to me this method? If I send an `index as 4,` what does the `code` return actually?.

```
def getOffset(index)
    @baseIndex = 0 if @baseIndex.nil?
    raise IndexError if not \
           (@baseIndex ... @baseIndex + length) === index
    return index - @baseIndex
end
```

I am not able to understand the part after the first line.

Comment: it returns the parameter, minus a baseIndex you can set

Comment: Have to tried to call `getOffset(4)`?

Comment: @Stefan: I want to understand the code after the first line..

Comment: @Mathew what is unclear in particular? Could be concept of raising errors, the inline `if`, the `not` keyword, the `...` literal or maybe the case equality `===`. Please clarify.

Comment: WHy is there so much of downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cleaning up your code

Your method's second line looks pretty confusing, let's refactor it:

```
raise IndexError if not \
       (@baseIndex ... @baseIndex + length) === index
```

The above is actually a single line:

```
raise IndexError if not (@baseIndex ... @baseIndex + length) === index
```

The case equality operator [`Range#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) should not be called explicitly. Use [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) instead, which does the same:

```
raise IndexError if not (@baseIndex ... @baseIndex + length).include?(index)
```

Finally, `if not` can be written as `unless` and some spaces can be removed:

```
raise IndexError unless (@baseIndex...@baseIndex + length).include?(index)
```

Better.

#### What does it do?

Let's assume `@baseIndex = 4` and `length = 10`:

```
raise IndexError unless (@baseIndex...@baseIndex + length).include?(index)
# is evaluated as:
raise IndexError unless (4...4 + 10).include?(index)
# is evaluated as:
raise IndexError unless (4...14).include?(index)
```

It raises an `IndexError` unless `index` is between `4` and `14` (excluding 14). Otherwise, it continues with the next line and returns `index - @baseIndex`.

#### What else?

- use `snake_case` for method names and variables (`@base_index`)
- don't write `return` unless necessary
- avoid `get` and `set` prefixes, i.e. `def offset` is usually enough
- initialize `@base_index` in your `initializer` (not in your `offset` method):

  ```
  def initialize
    @base_index = 0
  end
  ```
- extract the range calculation:

  ```
  def valid_range
    @base_index...@base_index + length
  end

  def offset(index)
    raise IndexError unless valid_range.include?(index)
    index - @base_index
  end
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. WHat is the purpose of thie method... given an index of an array a[4] what does this return me...

Comment: Very good explanation, Stefan. +1 Perhaps point out that `length => nil`. In situations like this I prefer [Range#cover?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F), as the former only looks at endpoints, whereas the latter examines all elements of the Range unless the endpoints are numeric. Here the endpoints are numeric so it makes no difference, but I think `cover` reads better.  (It took me awhile understand why `Range#include` couldn't always use just the endpoints.)

Answer (score 1):

```
# this sets the base index to 0 unless `@baseIndex` is defined
@baseIndex = 0 if @baseIndex.nil? 

# this raises an error if the index you passed in is larger than the size of your array
raise IndexError if not (@baseIndex ... @baseIndex + length) === index 

# this returns the offset
return index - @baseIndex
```

So, if you did not set `@baseIndex` and passed `4`, this method would return `4`.
If you set `@baseIndex` to `2`, this method would return `2`.
If you set `@baseIndex` to `5`, this method would return an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

`===` is used to test equality within a `when` clause of a `case` statement.

For example:

```
(1...10) === 5 returns true.
(1...10) === 11 returns false.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also refactor the code a bit for readability such as

```
def get_offset_refactor(index)
  @base_index ||= 0
  (@base_index...@base_index + length).include?(index) ? index - @base_index : raise IndexError 
end
```

This reads as

```
#if base index is not nil use it's value otherwise use 0
@base_index = @base_index || 0
#create a range from @base_index up to be not including @base_index + length
#check if index is included in that range
#if so then return index - @base_index
#otherwise raise an IndexError
(@base_index ... @base_index + length).include?(index) ? index - @base_index : raise IndexError
```

Example

```
#because this is not defined anywhere
def length
  5
end
get_offset_refactor(4)

@base_index = @base_index || 0 #@base_index will now = 0 because it was not set 
#next line becomes
(0...(0+5)).include?(4) ? 4 - 0 : raise(IndexError) 
#^[0,1,2,3,4]        ^does this include 4 => yes
#return 4 - 0
#=> 4
```

If you run it with a 5 then it will raise because `[1,2,3,4]` does not include `5`.

Hope this helps you understand this method is highly reliant on one instance variable `@base_index` and 1 method/local variable `length`.